# Error: "unsupported locale setting" on Python / OSX

Tags: python, django, macos, locale

I've got the following error trying to run a local Python scriot on OSX Lion 10.7:

```
You are using the base settings file.
You are advised to create a local.py file (based on local_sample.py) with your personal settings.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 39, in <module>
    detect_port(sys.argv)
  File "manage.py", line 22, in detect_port
    default_port = getattr(settings, 'RUNSERVER_PORT', None)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/vhsmaia/Viclib/site/orama_web/settings/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from base import *
  File "/Users/vhsmaia/Viclib/site/orama_web/settings/base.py", line 115, in <module>
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, LOCALE)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 531, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

Which tracks to the last line of this snippet on the file `base.py`:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'  # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-br'  # http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    LOCALE = 'ptb_bra'
else:
    LOCALE = ('pt_BR', 'UTF-8')
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, LOCALE)
```

The error stops working if I change LOCALE to `'pt_BR'` instead of that tuple.

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but this is the output of `locale -a`:

```
af_ZA
af_ZA.ISO8859-1
af_ZA.ISO8859-15
af_ZA.UTF-8
am_ET
am_ET.UTF-8
be_BY
be_BY.CP1131
be_BY.CP1251
be_BY.ISO8859-5
be_BY.UTF-8
bg_BG
bg_BG.CP1251
bg_BG.UTF-8
ca_ES
ca_ES.ISO8859-1
ca_ES.ISO8859-15
ca_ES.UTF-8
cs_CZ
cs_CZ.ISO8859-2
cs_CZ.UTF-8
da_DK
da_DK.ISO8859-1
da_DK.ISO8859-15
da_DK.UTF-8
de_AT
de_AT.ISO8859-1
de_AT.ISO8859-15
de_AT.UTF-8
de_CH
de_CH.ISO8859-1
de_CH.ISO8859-15
de_CH.UTF-8
de_DE
de_DE.ISO8859-1
de_DE.ISO8859-15
de_DE.UTF-8
el_GR
el_GR.ISO8859-7
el_GR.UTF-8
en_AU
en_AU.ISO8859-1
en_AU.ISO8859-15
en_AU.US-ASCII
en_AU.UTF-8
en_CA
en_CA.ISO8859-1
en_CA.ISO8859-15
en_CA.US-ASCII
en_CA.UTF-8
en_GB
en_GB.ISO8859-1
en_GB.ISO8859-15
en_GB.US-ASCII
en_GB.UTF-8
en_IE
en_IE.UTF-8
en_NZ
en_NZ.ISO8859-1
en_NZ.ISO8859-15
en_NZ.US-ASCII
en_NZ.UTF-8
en_US
en_US.ISO8859-1
en_US.ISO8859-15
en_US.US-ASCII
en_US.UTF-8
es_ES
es_ES.ISO8859-1
es_ES.ISO8859-15
es_ES.UTF-8
et_EE
et_EE.ISO8859-15
et_EE.UTF-8
eu_ES
eu_ES.ISO8859-1
eu_ES.ISO8859-15
eu_ES.UTF-8
fi_FI
fi_FI.ISO8859-1
fi_FI.ISO8859-15
fi_FI.UTF-8
fr_BE
fr_BE.ISO8859-1
fr_BE.ISO8859-15
fr_BE.UTF-8
fr_CA
fr_CA.ISO8859-1
fr_CA.ISO8859-15
fr_CA.UTF-8
fr_CH
fr_CH.ISO8859-1
fr_CH.ISO8859-15
fr_CH.UTF-8
fr_FR
fr_FR.ISO8859-1
fr_FR.ISO8859-15
fr_FR.UTF-8
he_IL
he_IL.UTF-8
hi_IN.ISCII-DEV
hr_HR
hr_HR.ISO8859-2
hr_HR.UTF-8
hu_HU
hu_HU.ISO8859-2
hu_HU.UTF-8
hy_AM
hy_AM.ARMSCII-8
hy_AM.UTF-8
is_IS
is_IS.ISO8859-1
is_IS.ISO8859-15
is_IS.UTF-8
it_CH
it_CH.ISO8859-1
it_CH.ISO8859-15
it_CH.UTF-8
it_IT
it_IT.ISO8859-1
it_IT.ISO8859-15
it_IT.UTF-8
ja_JP
ja_JP.eucJP
ja_JP.SJIS
ja_JP.UTF-8
kk_KZ
kk_KZ.PT154
kk_KZ.UTF-8
ko_KR
ko_KR.CP949
ko_KR.eucKR
ko_KR.UTF-8
lt_LT
lt_LT.ISO8859-13
lt_LT.ISO8859-4
lt_LT.UTF-8
nl_BE
nl_BE.ISO8859-1
nl_BE.ISO8859-15
nl_BE.UTF-8
nl_NL
nl_NL.ISO8859-1
nl_NL.ISO8859-15
nl_NL.UTF-8
no_NO
no_NO.ISO8859-1
no_NO.ISO8859-15
no_NO.UTF-8
pl_PL
pl_PL.ISO8859-2
pl_PL.UTF-8
pt_BR
pt_BR.ISO8859-1
pt_BR.UTF-8
pt_PT
pt_PT.ISO8859-1
pt_PT.ISO8859-15
pt_PT.UTF-8
ro_RO
ro_RO.ISO8859-2
ro_RO.UTF-8
ru_RU
ru_RU.CP1251
ru_RU.CP866
ru_RU.ISO8859-5
ru_RU.KOI8-R
ru_RU.UTF-8
sk_SK
sk_SK.ISO8859-2
sk_SK.UTF-8
sl_SI
sl_SI.ISO8859-2
sl_SI.UTF-8
sr_YU
sr_YU.ISO8859-2
sr_YU.ISO8859-5
sr_YU.UTF-8
sv_SE
sv_SE.ISO8859-1
sv_SE.ISO8859-15
sv_SE.UTF-8
tr_TR
tr_TR.ISO8859-9
tr_TR.UTF-8
uk_UA
uk_UA.ISO8859-5
uk_UA.KOI8-U
uk_UA.UTF-8
zh_CN
zh_CN.eucCN
zh_CN.GB18030
zh_CN.GB2312
zh_CN.GBK
zh_CN.UTF-8
zh_HK
zh_HK.Big5HKSCS
zh_HK.UTF-8
zh_TW
zh_TW.Big5
zh_TW.UTF-8
C
```

And this is the output of `locale`:

```
LANG="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="pt_BR.UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This did the trick for me, write the one you want verbatim. I have 2 exception blocks because I use linux and osx:

Where in your code do you set it? This works for me, since the Linux and OSX machines vary and I use my code on both, I wrote this exception block:

```
try:
    import locale
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8')
except Exception:
    try:
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
    except Exception as e:
        messages.error(request, 'An error occurred: {0}'.format(e))
```

My locale outputs:

```
locale
LANG="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Eh... wow. I don't even remember that problem. Hope this helps someone on the internet!

Comment: I ran into it when porting my python project from linux to osx (for development under osx). The differences in syntax gave me this error.

Comment: The other way around, set up the project for osx, was helpful to port to linux.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you do not have the locales. Add it as follows:

Check which locales are supported:

```
locale -a
```

Add the locales you want (for example pt):

```
sudo locale-gen pt_BR

sudo locale-gen pt_BR.UTF-8
```

Run this update command:

```
sudo update-locale
```