# unsupported locale setting Mac python

Tags: python

I'm trying to change the language of a column `week_names` from English to Spanish

This is the code :

```
dias_semana=pd.to_datetime(fechas['Fecha'], format='%Y/%m/%d').dt.day_name(locale= "Spanish")
dias_semana=pd.DataFrame(dias_semana)
```

and the error is this:

```
Error: unsupported locale setting
```

I'm running python in Jupyter notebook, Mac OS Big Sur 11.1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: "unsupported locale setting" on Python / OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994358/error-unsupported-locale-setting-on-python-osx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try to import the `locale` library first:

```py
import locale

locale.setlocale(category=locale.LC_ALL,
                 locale="German"  # Note: do not use "de_DE" as it doesn't work)
```

In your case, you would replace `German` by `Spanish`

You also might have some luck with:

```py
try:
    import locale
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8')
except Exception:
    try:
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
    except Exception as e:
        messages.error(request, 'An error occurred: {0}'.format(e))
```

It is also possible to set LC_ALL in your environment by running the following command:

```sh
$ export LC_ALL=C
```

If that doesn't help, then you can try to install dpkg using `sudo port install dpkg` or `brew` (http://macappstore.org/dpkg/)

And then the following:

```sh
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

For your case, I believe the locale would be `'es_ES.UTF-8'`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When I try 'German' or any other language I get: locale.Error: unsupported locale setting.